# 650 points inside a circle of radius 16

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

*There are 650 points inside a circle of radius 16. Prove there exists a ring with inner radius 2 and outer radius 3 covering 10 of these points.*

Hint of the professor: Use Dirichlet's (pigeonhole) principle.

---

EDIT: (after the solution became known) Lets call this problem (650, 16, 10). Lets see if we can find another (N, R, M) instances of the problem. (ring (annulus) would stay the same)

According to the solution below, this condition is crucial for proof:

$N\cdot(3^2-2^2)\pi>(M-1)(R+3)^2\pi$ , or

$N>(M-1)(R+3)^2/5$

For $R=16$ and $M=10$, the condition is $N>649.8$.

Lets choose something smaller, $R=5$ and $M=7$, the condition is $N>76.8$.

Or larger, $R=31$ and $M=20$, the condition is $N>4392.8$.

So, following problems are also valid:

*There are 77 points inside a circle of radius 5. Prove there exists a ring with inner radius 2 and outer radius 3 covering 7 of these points.* (this turned out nice enigmatic combination 7-77-5-2)

*There are 4393 points inside a circle of radius 31. Prove there exists a ring with inner radius 2 and outer radius 3 covering 20 of these points.* (pretty scary sounding problem)

Comment: What's preventing all points being on a circle of radius $1$?

Comment: @DavidPeterson Is your question rhetorical?

Comment: @DavidPeterson:  Nothing, but then I can find an annulus as described that covers more than half the circle, so will cover more than $10$ of them.

Comment: Well, if you can find a covering of the circle of radius $16$ by less or equal than $65$ rings of radii $2,3$, then by the pigeonhole you're done.

Comment: Nothing. But I guess this is not counterexample.

Comment: $\#6$ of http://web.mit.edu/~holden1/www/math/high_school/Box.pdf  (Hard) or $#13$ of http://www.iucaa.ernet.in/~paddy/playthemes/playthemes.htm or $\#11$ of http://www.ms.uky.edu/~lee/ma310/prob/node38.html :)

Comment: My fault, I was erroneously thinking everything was centered on the same point

Comment: The problem is hard.

Comment: OK, @Hagen von Eitzen solved the problem, I guess, in a sharp and elegant way. But, why stop there? We are all solving problems, but who designs/invents them? That's a kind of higher level of skill or knowledge. It would be nice to state at least several new problems, based on this.

Comment: @David Peterson, do you have some comment?

Comment: @Ross Millikan, do you from time to time "make" problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Around each of the points, draw such an annulus. Then all $650$ annuli are contained within an enlarged circle of radius $19$ and area $19^2\pi$. The sum of the annulus areas is $650\cdot(3^2-2^2)\pi$. This is more than $9\cdot19^2 \pi$ (just slightly: $\frac{650\cdot (3^2-2^2)}{19^2}\approx 9.00277$) , hence some point must be covered at least tenfold. Conversely, the annulus around this point contains at least ten of the original points.

Comment: Gorgeous! :o :)

Comment: Is there a way to construct ("invent") similar problems, just with different numbers? Or shapes?